# Выпадающий поиск, как в гугле

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, ajax, php, javascript

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ы</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search").keyup(function(){
          $("#search").autocomplete("json.php", {
            delay:10,
            minChars:4,
            maxItemsToShow:3
            }
          );
          }); });
      //?word=" + $("#search-text").val()
</script>
<form action=""><input type="search" id="search"> <input type="submit"></form>
<body>
```

json.php

```
<?php
echo json_decode($_GET['q']);
```

Как сделать чтоб работало? Здесь можно использовать файл json?

Comment: Имеете ввиду, как реализовать серверную часть ?

Comment: да. может есть решения лучше?

Comment: `json_decode($_GET['q'], true)` это раз и второе --- НИКОГДА так не делайте ;) обрабатывать GET/POST запросы не проверяя их приведет к плачевным последствиям...

Comment: ясное дело нужно делать проверку. вопрос был в взаимодействии сущностей.

Comment: ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ОТВЕТ. echo 'word,word1,word2'; + lineSeparator: ','

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, правильно (наверное, лучше обратиться к документации autocomplete) после получения результата обратно `json_encode(ответ)` в соответствии с документацией autocomplete :) Наверняка, у разработчика и примеры есть на сайте даже?

описание как это рабтает все же [есть](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) или вот [больше подойдет](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) :)

возвращается `json` в удобном Вам виде, в последнем примере показано это.

и вообще. есть [отличный туториал](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/) по Вашему `jqueryui autocomplete`

Comment: там нет серверной стороны

Comment: тогда ставьте `firebug`, к примеру, и смотрите что посылает `autocomplete` (в каком формате и с какими переменными) и что возвращает сервер, в частности `json.php`

если я правильно нашел ваш autocomplete, то там все написано:

> The backend should output possible values for the autocompleter, each on a single line. Output cannot contain the pipe symbol "|", since that is considered a separator (more on that later). Using options you could also opt for receiving data in JSON format.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
там такого текста нет, в любом случае это не пример. посмотрел ответ, 200ок. тела нет. echo json_decode($_GET['q']); тут ошибка, вопрос в том где?

Comment: да, нашел не то... ^) но не важно, работает оно все одинаково, к тому же описание как это рабтает все же [есть](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) :)